# How far apart should speed bumps be placed so that a car will bounce more and more violently?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose the suspension system of the average car can be fairly well modeled by an underdamped harmonic oscillator with a natural period of 2 seconds. How far apart should speed bumps be placed so that a car travelling at 15 mph over several bumps will bounce more and more violently with each bump?

My idea:

An underdamped system would have the damping coefficient $\gamma <2 \sqrt{km}$, where $k$ is the spring coefficient and $m$ is the mass of the car. Neither of these values were provided in the problem.

Since the car is travelling at 15 mph, $u'(t)=15$mph.

The period is 2 seconds, so $2=T=2\pi / \omega_0$, which implies $\omega_0=\pi$.

This is the most amount of information that I could extract from this problem. How should I approach solving this problem?

Comment: A friendly word of advice:  don't try this "in real life ".  It can in fact be rather dangerous.  Ask me how I know.  Cheers!

Comment: @RobertLewis How do you know?

Comment: I drove a car over a road with a series of speed bumps at just the right (wrong?) speed.  The suspension began to oscillate wildly.  That's how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming this problem is from a physics/engineering class and to solve it you are supposed to use the fact that you achieve an increasing amplitude if you push the harmonic oscillator at it's eigenfrequency. Thus, the bumps should happen every two seconds. So you just need to calculate how far a car with 15 mph travels in 2 seconds.

If this answer does not satisfy you, let me know so I can provide you one including the ODE.

Comment: Thank you for providing your insight to the problem. This is actually a problem from my ordinary differential equations course, so I assume that I need to use ODEs to find the solution. If possible, could you shed some light on how to do that?